# Decimal Values Animation issue in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I have  created an animation for the number,when set it to  lower values like 0.25 values ,the last digit is not animating , i am expecting this number to animate 0.19,0.20,0.21,0.22,0.23, to reach result.

But when we provide the values as 20.9 it is animating . can anyone help me on this.

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
  $({
    countNum: $this.text()
  }).animate({
      countNum: countTo
    },
    {
      duration: 8000,
      easing: 'linear',
      step: function() {
        $this.text(Math.round(this.countNum * 10 / 10));
      },
      complete: function() {
        $this.text(this.countNum);
        //alert('finished');
      }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #F46A6A;
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

.counter {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 1.5%;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: #FF6F6F;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter" data-count="0.25">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-count="21.9">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-count="2200">0</div>
```

Here is the online demo.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RMwPox

Comment: What do you think Math.round() is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Open the dev tools, select the console tab and type this:

```
Math.round(0.25);
```

Looking at that result will demonstrate that your code is doing exactly what you've asked it to do.

You will need to use `.toFixed(2)` or some other solution to ensure that you get both decimals considered. You will need to make a choice about output then because all three will show 2 decimal places.

The reason it *appears* that 21.9 works is because when it is rounded up to 22, the animation *looks* correct because at the end you exchange the final result (22) with the actual input 21.9 - they are so close it isn't noticed.